# How to view encrypted html code in c#

Tags: c#, html, .net

I have an application that uses `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` to get the html text of a page but the text I get the information I need is inside a `Div` however to that `Div` when I get it in the application it appears empty with no information inside.

Using google chrome in *inspect* mode I can see the information inside the div already in the *view source* the information does not appear.

Can someone help me out as I get this information using ***C#***

My code:

```
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://portal.cfm.org.br/index.php?option=com_medicos&Itemid=59");
request.Proxy = webProxy;
request.Timeout = 80000;
request.Method = "GET";
request.KeepAlive = true;
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding);
html = sr.ReadToEnd();
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

Div that comes with the code:

```html
<div id="resultadoMedicos"><dl id="system-message" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; display: block; min-height: 120px; height: auto;">
<dt>A sequ&ecirc;ncia de caracteres digitada n&atilde;o confere com a da imagem exibida. Por favor, preencha o campo novamente.</dt>
<dd class="message fade">
<ul>
<li></li>
</ul>
</dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

Original Div(with the information i need):

```html
<div id="resultadoMedicos"><table id="tableMedicos" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="tableHeaderMedicos">
<td class="valorNome"><span>Nome do Médico</span></td>
<td class="valorSituacao"><span>Situação</span></td>
<td class="valorCRM"><span>CRM</span></td>
<td class="valorUF"><span>Estado</span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="regRow regRow0 row row0 medRow" crm="152756" uf="SP" style="display: table-row;">
<td class="valorNome"><span>Alan Felipe Sakai</span></td>
<td class="valorSituacao"><span>Regular</span></td>
<td class="valorCRM"><span>152756</span></td>
<td class="valorUF"><span>SP</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need to get some data on the Server side - you have to POST it. You could use simple form or some JS for that purposes

Comment: Div contents are not normally submitted on forms. Can you provide code samples for more insight?

Comment: @rabelloo I put my code and how the div comes through my code and how is it original with the information the way I need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message translates to: *"The typed sequence of characters does not match that of the displayed image. Please fill in the field again."*

Looks like the site is using a CAPTCHA to prevent you from scraping the data in this way.

Unless you can get the site owners to provide you with a direct feed of their data, you're not going to be able to extract the information.